# try and catch error with joptionpane

Tags: java

netbeans says in exception e that variable e is not used. I don't seem to understand the problem.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DecimalFormat z = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    double x = Double.parseDouble(fnum.getText());     
    double y = Double.parseDouble(secondnum.getText());

    try {
        double f = x + y;
        String number = z.format(f);
        answer.setText("" + number);
    } catch(Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please input a valid number");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just a warning... You can ignore it. Your code will still compile and run.

Comment: You are catching an exception ,but not using it . Normally IDE gives the warning messages when you create an object and not used anywhere. Just logging the exception is enough  if you are worring about the warning

Comment: the try catch block doesn't work

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Define: [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: when i input a letter instead of a number

Comment: nothing happens no message dialouge showing an error

Comment: Can I just mention it's bad practice to catch a generic exception. You should try to be as specific as is practical with your exceptions for better bug huntability.

Comment: Try using the "e" in catch.

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please input a valid number" + e.getMessage());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning (which can be ignored) is telling you that the variable `e` you've declared in your catch block is not used. I know with IntelliJ IDEA you can remove the warning by changing the name of `e` to `ignored`. I'm not sure if NetBeans has a similar feature.

However, your try block is rather pointless. It should be around your `Double.parseDouble()` calls, because those are what will fail if the input from the user was not something that could be interpreted as a number. The only method within your try block that could potentially throw an exception would be `z.format(f)` and only if `z` had its rounding mode set to `RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY` which it isn't by default.

Try something more like this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DecimalFormat z = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    try  {
      double x = Double.parseDouble(fnum.getText());     
      double y = Double.parseDouble(secondnum.getText());
      double f = x + y;
      String number = z.format(f);
      answer.setText("" + number);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please input a valid number");
    }
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments on OP, catching Exception is not generally recommended, so updated to catch the more specific NumberFormatException instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's true - a variable e is not used.
To fix this issue (warning in fact) you can for instance print this exception.

Example:

```
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please input a valid number");}
```

Comment: message box not closing for me.help please...tried the same.